# Modification of a CW-Complex $X$ with control over Homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, higher-homotopy-groups

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional CW-complex, ie we endow it with CW structure such that there exist a $n_0>0$ such that there are no $n$-simplices for $n>n_0$. Let $[\beta] \in H_k(X, \mathbb{Z}), k \le n_0$ a nonzero homology class.

*Question:* Is it possible to modify $X$ to another CW-complex $X'$ in following good controlled manner:

1. There exist cellular map $f: X \to X'$, ie commutes the differentials of associated complexes $(C(X), \partial)$ and $(C(X'), \partial')$
2. the induced maps $f_i: H_i(X) \to H_i(X')$ are all isomorphic for $i \neq k$
3. $f_k: H_k(X) \to H_k(X')$ is surjective and $f_k([\beta])=0$

Is such modification always possible and if yes is there any geometrical intuition behind this construction?

Motivation: For homotopy groups we can always 'kill' a class $[\alpha] \in \pi_k(X)$ by modyfying $X$ via glueing a $(k+1)$-ball along map $\alpha: S^k \to X$ representing the class $[\alpha]$ and obtaining modified space $X':=X \cup_{\alpha}D^{k+1}$ which does the job for all homotopy groups $m < k$. On the other hand this modification not doesn't give any control over homotogy groups with $m >n$.
The general slogan is that 'homology is easier to control that homotopy', so I would like to know if it's possible to modify $X$ to a space $X'$ satisfying properties 1,2 and 3.

My ideas: The chain complex $(C_n, \partial_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ comprises by construction in each degree $n$ of the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module $C_n$ generated by $n$-simplices and differentials $\partial_n: C_n \to C_{n-1}$. If we want to kill cycle $[\beta]\in H_k(X)$ say represented by a chain $\beta= \sum_i c_i \sigma_i^k$ with $\sigma_i^k$ the $k$-simplices and only finitely many $a_i \neq 0$, we have to add some $k+1$-simplices to $C_{k+1}$, making $\beta$ a boundary, ie an image under $\partial_{k+1}$. Is it always possible?

If yes, there is another new problem. We want $H_{k+1}(X)=H_{k+1}(X')$, so these new $k+1$-simplices cannot contribute to homology, so must be boundaries too, so we play the same game with $k+2$-simplices. But I not see how can finish this adding new simplicies game when arriving $H_{n_0}(X)$.

Comment: Do you mean $k \leq n_0$? For a CW complex of dimension $n_0$, all homology groups above dimension $n_0$ are trivial.

Comment: @kamills: yes, thanks

Comment: The problem you run into at the end of your discussion is exactly the issue with having such a possible modification. For example, for $X = S^n$ and $\beta$ the generator of $H_n(S^n)$, to kill this satisfying your list of axioms you'd obtain a space $X'$ with the homology of a point. You can kill a class if you want by the construction you say (add a cell whose boundary is represented by the class $\beta$), but if you want any meaningful result you can't actually guarantee that you haven't changed the higher homology groups.

Comment: The difference between this and the homotopy situation is: when you kill a $k$-dimensional homology class you may have introduced some $(k+1)$-dimensional homology, but you haven't introduced any potentially higher homology. But when you kill a $k$-dimensional homotopy class, you may have introduced higher homotopy in all degrees $>k$.

Comment: @kamills: I see, so essentially trying to construct the modification $X'$ satisfying the conditions runs in the same troubles as 
in case with *homotopy* groups, namely the loss of control over $H_n(X')$ for $n>n_0$, right? Ok, let give up the control over higher 
homology groups and replace my condition 2. by weaker condition say $(2')$ that we want $f_i: H_i(X) \to H_i(X')$ be iso only for $n_0 >i$.

Comment: Let assume this for the moment. What I 
still not understand is why can we *always* kill a class $\beta \in H_k(X)$ by adding a single $(k+1)$ cell? Is it always possible to 
glue it to $X$ in the way that it's boundary equals $\beta$? In general $\beta$ is represented by a formal sum $\sum a_i \sigma_i$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$
 (or in more general ring) and $\sigma$ $k$-simplices. It make intuitively sense in dimension $1$ by choosing a $2$-ball and glueing it 
along the $1$-cycle representing $\beta$ to $X$. But does it alwo work in higher dimensions in the same way?

Comment: I'm just wondering if 
in higher dimension there not might occure some geometric restruction, since in general it cannot be expected that *every* algebraic map , ie a$\mathbb{Z}$-module map $C_{k+1}(X) \to C_k(X)$ can be realized from geometry, ie determined by how $k+1$-cells are glued.

Comment: Good point, you're right. However, if you work in cellular homology with the cellular chain complex, follow this argument: A $k$-dimensional generator of the homology is a $k$-cell whose (cellular) boundary is zero but isn't the (cellular) boundary of a higher cell. Chasing through the definition of the cellular boundary map, you can see that after adding a $(k+1)$-cell with attaching map the identity onto your desired $k$-cell, the $k$-cell is in the image of the cellular boundary map so the class dies. So you can at least kill generators with single cells. Otherwise you may need more cells.

Comment: @kamills: But following your definition of a $k$-dimensional generator, these in general (as $\mathbb{Z}$-module) not generate the whole $H_k(X)$ right? So the central problem in the question boils down to the question if for a fixed $k$-chain $\beta= \sum_i c_i \sigma_i^k$ always possible to modify $X$ by attaching some $k+1$-cells such that in the resulting complex $C_*(X')$ the chain $\beta$ is a boundary.

Comment: Indeed, once having this by construction of chains the $m$-th homology groups of $X$ and $X'$ coincide for $k >m$ and $m \ge k+2$ since for these $m$ neither the chain groups $C_m(X)$, nor the differentials change (that's exactly the content of your third comment: adding $k+1$-cells affects only $k$-the and $(k+1)$-homologies, not the others in contract to *homotopy* groups).

Comment: @kamills: An update: I think in full generality it's hopeless to expect that $\beta$ can be killed by attaching $k+1$-cell: Consider just any CW complex $X$ with $\pi_k(X)=0$, but $H_k(X) \neq 0$, so morally we are looking for CW complexes where the homology groups $H_k(X)$ elude any control by homotopy groups via Hurewicz map $\pi_k(X) \to H_k(X)$, and there are countless many spaces where Hurewicz map gives almost no information about the relation between homology and and homotopy

Comment: But by the way in your previous "However, if you work in cellular homology"-comment you gave a criterion which seemingly contradict to my last comment. Could you give a reference where you found this result? Maybe it requires additional assumptions on $X$, otherwise that obviously fails for spaces with  $\pi_k(X)=0$ and $H_k(X) \neq 0$ from my last comment

Comment: Yeah, I realized that the problem with my comment is that the $k$-cell representing your class may not appear in $X$ as an embedded sphere (up to homotopy, I guess). When it does, you can follow the construction; when it doesn't, you can't guarantee that you can use the identity map for attaching. But, this class appearing in $X$ as an embedded sphere is the same thing as saying it's in the image of the Hurewicz map $\pi_k(X) \to H_k(X)$. So this is certainly true in the range where Hurewicz applies, and otherwise you have no shot of saying anything in full generality. Nice catch.